# Delete some class files in visual studio, but calling them still works

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am not sure if this is a problem with visual studio, but I had some class files that I deleted, but I can still call them in my code.  Also I can call a .edmx i created, but I cant see it in my folder, i tried rebuilding my solution, cleaning it, rerunning it, checking source files.  Its also causing a lot of my classes to have this error:

Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'MatchGaming.Models.MyProfile'; another partial declaration of this type exists

I already tried adding partial and it i just get a bunch of errors everywhere else saying that a lot of my variables already contain a definition, almost like theres a duplicate class stuck in the cache or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, had to delete some xml in the web.config file